# Fire javascript function on image click within a html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains an image :

```
<div class="HD">
    <img class="image1"src="img/myimage.png">
</div>
```

the CSS applied to it is :

```
.HD img {
    position:absolute;
    top:570px;
    left:1120px;
    width:30px;
    height:90px;
    cursor:pointer
}
```

I want to apply a click function to the image inside the div. However, when I give an image id or class and use that to create the function the javascript does not fire. When the div does not have an image and I use the class the javascript works as expected. 
Below is the Javascript function  :

```
$(".HD").click(function () {
    if($('.UpperDiv').attr('data-visible') == "hidden") {
        $('.UpperDiv').attr('data-visible', 'visible');
        $('.UpperDiv').animate({
            opacity:1
            // top:'250px'
        });
    } else {
        $('.UpperDiv').attr('data-visible','hidden');
        $('.UpperDiv').animate({
            opacity:0
            // top:'250px'
        });
    }
});
```

What could be the reason ? What is wrong with my code ?
How can I fire the javascript, when the user clicks on a div that contains an image?

For reference, this is the website I am [trying to make](http://www.realmusicom.com/demo/), and the [original working version](http://www.realmusicom.com/demo1).

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: I have not used jsfiddle .. I am trying to create one .. will that be useful if i did

Comment: Yes, definitely would be helpful for answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$(".HD").on({
    click : function(){
        if($('.UpperDiv').attr('data-visible')=="hidden")
        {
                $('.UpperDiv').attr('data-visible','visible');
                $('.UpperDiv').animate({
                        opacity:1
                        // top:'250px'
                });
        }else{
                $('.UpperDiv').attr('data-visible','hidden');
                $('.UpperDiv').animate({
                        opacity:0
                        // top:'250px'
                });
        }
    }
}, 'img');
```

Comment: Is there a way we could apply an image class or image id and on click of that fire the javascript .. Thank you for the answer though it does provide useful suggestions

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use [.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

```
$(".HD").toggle(400);
```

Or [.fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)?

```
$(".HD").fadeToggle();
```

Comment: I am sorry , I could not understand your answer ..why did you suggest the toggle .. will the toggle thing toggle between the 2 divs's.. but the current problem is that nothing happens on a click..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".HD > img").click(function () { });
```

Use this and try.